# MATLAB: ifft after fft does not give the original result

Tags: matlab, fft, ifft

I apply `ifft` after `fft`, but the result is not the same `(x-fft(ifft(x))` is different from zero)? Where is the mistake?

Comment: Do you mean nonzero such as $10^{-15}$ terms...? (assuming normalized input)

Comment: No, more 10^7 where x is of the order of 10^8

Comment: Maybe something with fftshift, but I already checked that...

Comment: Can you provide an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @GrapefruitlsAwesome: of course, I will edit the question

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with another data set... probably something wrong with the data

Comment: The ratio is about 10^(-1)

Comment: The problem is the assignment in matlab:

Comment: psix=ifft(psik); psik is not equal to fft(psix); But psik is equal to fft(ifft(psik))

Comment: Try abs(x)-abs(fft(ifft(x))

Comment: Could You close this post @AndyWalls

Comment: You can see FFT as a matrix operation and IFFT a multiplication by the inverse, hence the results must be the same. Any differences are due to errors in digital representation of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is numerical noise.  Matlab uses 64-bit floating point numbers and so the results are not the same that you would get with infinite precision or with pencil and paper.

Typical signal to noise ratio would be in the range of 300 dB

See example

```
%% FFT numerical noise
x = randn(1024,1); % start with normal distributed noise
% FFT and back calculate difference
d = ifft(fft(x))- x;
fprintf('Error = %6.2fdB\n',10*log10(sum(d.^2)./sum(x.^2)));
```

Comes out below -300dB

## Update Complex example:

Same result for complex data

```
%% complex
x = randn(1024,1)+1i*rand(1024,1); % start with normal distributed noise
% FFT and back calculate difference
d = ifft(fft(x))- x;
% error
fprintf('Error = %6.2fdB\n',10*log10(sum(d.*conj(d))./sum(x.*conj(x))));
```

Comment: There is a fairly large difference still (50%)

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. I added at example

Comment: it is with complex numbers signal

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @userxxxxx: complex makes no difference here . See updated answer